# Oracle SQL Look through column, if condition fulfill, compare dates and insert value to column

Tags: sql, oracle

need help with oracle sql code. I want my code able to do something like this:
Look for `Event:TS-0068` then take the Task Number value '55', then look for next '55' with 'EVENT:BC-0050' and compare both date.If Event:TS-0068,date A smaller than Event:BC-0050,Date B then return string "Overhead" at column Condition, else Null or blank will do. I include test data here in link
[Dummy Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1seCPue5ibM_adMsi9tBmTOrRAPIcis_H/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: Please rephrase your question by including sample data as _text_, not as an image, and also show us the output.

Comment: Sorry i just totally no idea to write code for this oracle sql. It seem impossible to do in this tableau, but since my tableau datasource from sql, so i was thinking perhaps i can filter it out 1st from oracle sql then only port into tableau.

Comment: I do read article & example on using lag/lead function and prevr/nextr function but not sure combine & construct the code

Comment: @LeoEY . . . Your description is not consistent with the results, because it should be setting all the 55 events with "Overhead".  Do you just want the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditions translate directly into analytic functions and `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when text2 = 'EVENT:TS-0068' and TASK_NUMBER = 55 and
                  row_number() over (partition by text2, task_number order by starttime) = 1 and
                  min(case when text2 = 'EVENT:BC-0050' then starttime end) over (order by starttime desc) > starttime
             then 'Overhead'
        end) as condition
from t
order by starttime;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fe8ad6ea4c8bf5d4fe8940b87eb50ce6) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Determine the first record with `text2='EVENT:TS-0068'` when ordered by the start time through use of `dense_rank()` analytic function in the first query.

Then take only the records with returned dense_rank values equal to 1 in order to create condition column by use of a correlated subquery to scan whether there exists at least one record for `text2='EVENT:BC-0050'` exceeding starttime value those are for `text2='EVENT:TS-0068'` :

```
WITH t AS
(
 SELECT nvl(case 
            when text2 = 'EVENT:TS-0068' then
                 dense_rank() over (partition by text2 order by starttime)
            end, 0) as dr,
        t.*
   FROM tab t
  ORDER BY starttime
)
 SELECT starttime, text2, task_number,
        case 
        when dr = 1 then
           ( select nvl2( max(starttime), 'Overhead', null )
               from t t1
              where t.starttime < t1.starttime 
                and text2 = 'EVENT:BC-0050')
        end as condition
   FROM t
  ORDER BY starttime;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=89c936039d848e795dc100cffab8e870)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Definetly will try on this & post an update